# Can you create a child case of a child case in a normal module in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

How can I create a child case of a child case in one form in a normal module? Is it imperative to use advanced modules to achieve this kind of case creation in one form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot create a grandchild case in a form in a regular module.  Without using advanced modules, the best thing you could do would be to open a child case and then go into another form in a module of the child case type and open the grandchild case there.